# can't save phone number after reset factory

Tags: contacts, root-access, factory-reset, google-contacts

I recently rooted my cellphone after reset factory , but unfortunately I can't add phone number to contacts , How I can fix it? sony xperia J 4.1.2

Comment: Well, that's weird, do one thing try tapping over the menu>settings>application manager>Swipe left to all> Look out for contacts>tap over it clear the cache and the data stored. Once done try storing the contact again and see if that works out for you ?

Comment: @FarzanNjr, that's only half the answer I've asked for. Mind to [edit] your post again to include the other half? Quoting myself: *Did you something apart from rooting it? What approach did you take to root it?*